# Telegram Bot на node js отправка уведомления после перезагрузки сервера

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Делаю telegram bot на node js (node-telegram-bot-api). Задача рассылать юзерам определенные уведомления, после того как юзер на них подпишется. Как это правильно сделать? Я подключаю бот к MySQL и записываю user_id, тип уведомлений и т.п. Но, если после обновления сервер перезагружается (heroku), то как мне после перезагрузки заставить бота проверить подписан ли юзер на уведомления и отправить их в нужный момент?

Получить user_id пока юзер не отправит сообщения боту я не могу (как мне кажется).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Записываю в базу чат_id и дату уведомления. Сразу после перезагрузки сервер проверяет в базу есть ли чат_id подписанные на уведомления на эту дату. Если есть, то рассылает им нужные уведомления.

Answer (score 0):

добавь sendingTime(timestamp), по которому должен бот должен отправить сообщение  и флаг isSended(bool, default false) и сделай некий сканер, который будет ходить по этой таблице и отправлять уведомление, если текущее время больше sendingTime и isSended = false, после отправки обновлять isSended на true

Comment: Дело в том, что бот должен отправлять сообщение не всем, а только подписавшимся на уведомление. И после перезагрузки сервера я хотел чтобы бот бот проверял (без каких либо действий юзера), подписан ли данный юзер на уведомление, чтобы отправить в нужный момент. Но без того, чтобы юзер отправил сообщение, я не могу получить id чата или юзера для проверки. Вроде придумал другое решение, но вопрос пока актуален. Может есть идею лучше.